# Pre Populating recipients title on docusign via salesforce REST API

Tags: rest, salesforce, docusignapi

Is there a way to populate Recipients title when using embedded docusign functionality? We have a salesforce - docusign integration via REST based API. The recipient's name and date is being populated automatically, but the recipient's title is not being populated even though the recipient's title is being sent as part of the web service call. Let me know if the tile of the recipient can be pre-populated?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pre-populate Recipient Title using API, if the recipient has DocuSign account and has Title in his/her DS Account then DocuSign will automatically populate same title at the time of Signing. If you want to populate Title from your App, I would suggest you to use Text Tab instead of Title Tab, using Text Tab you can send the recipient titles via API.